# Save ACF upload field file from WooCommerce Admin single product settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, file-upload, advanced-custom-fields

I have successfully been able to add an ACF file upload field in WooCommerce Admin single product settings under product data (metabox) in the General (tab):

[image: woo cusomt file]

But the file is not getting saved when updating.

Here is my code:

```php
// Add ACF file type field to WooCommerce product general settings
function add_acf_file_field_to_woocommerce_product_options() {
    global $product_object; // Get the product object
    
    $product_id = $product_object->get_id(); // Get the product ID
    
    // Define the field settings
    $field_settings = array(
        'key' => 'field_my_file_field',
        'label' => 'File Field',
        'name' => 'my_file_field',
        'type' => 'file',
        'instructions' => 'Upload a file',
        'return_format' => 'url', // Change this to 'array' if you want more information about the file
    );

    // Render the ACF field
    acf_render_field_wrap($field_settings);

    // Handle form submission and update the ACF field
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['woocommerce_process_product_meta'])) {
        $file_field_value = $_POST['acf']['field_my_file_field'];
        
        // Update the ACF field value
        update_field('field_my_file_field', $file_field_value, $product_id);
    }
}

// Hook into WooCommerce product general options
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_acf_file_field_to_woocommerce_product_options');
```

Comment: You can't use file upload on any WooCommerce settings this way, it requires to be made with JS, Ajax and PHP admin Ajax. No other way.

Comment: Add the field outside of product data. ACF its not intended to work as product data.

Comment: i would apperciate @LoicTheAztec and Acf Official support team on updating me on few term i was trying to achieve on wrong way. I just want custom file uploader on **Product-data->general tab** woocoomerce have built hook for custom field like woocommerce_wp_text_input,woocommerce_wp_checkbox but it seems that it doesnt support file type. so i went with **ACF** i create acf field normally and used jquery append() to insert ACF field to Prodcut tab, which was successful but to shift ACF field from its original place to Product-data, its take few seconds, shfiting was clear visible

Comment: After analysing what @LoicTheAztec and ACF support team mention, finally i got working solution. We need to combine **ACF, Woocommerce and Wordpress** First of all we register ACF With **register_custom_acf_field()** to aviod duplication / conflict we will avoid 'Location' is registeration. Now after regsitering ACF field we Will display in **Product-datat->general tab with Woo->Hooks** and ACF function acf_form()

Comment: It seems that i cant write the solution comment, does allow me to write long but i have got working solution, Once again i would like to apperciate** @LoicTheAztec and ACF official Support Team** for pointing out, attempting wrong method to trying to achieve my requirement

Comment: If you have a working solution, you should answer your own question, once done notify me here please.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and your question actually helped me solve it. Here's how I would do it in your case

```
/**
 * Hook into WooCommerce product general options tab and add the custom file field
 */
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', function () {

    global $product_object;

    if (!function_exists('acf_render_field_wrap')) {
        return;
    }

    $field_settings = array(
        'key' => 'field_my_file_field',
        'label' => 'File Field',
        'name' => 'my_file_field',
        'type' => 'file',
        'instructions' => 'Upload a file',
        'return_format' => 'id',
        'value' => get_field('field_my_file_field', $product_object->get_id()) // get the value of the field
    );

    acf_render_field_wrap($field_settings);
});

/**
 * Save the value of the custom file field
 */
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', function ($product_id) {

    if (isset($_POST['field_my_file_field'])) {
        update_field('field_my_file_field', $_POST['field_my_file_field'], $product_id);
    }

});
```